# LineChart - перестроить график. JavaFX

Tags: javafx, график

Ребят, кто может привести как пример часть кода, где график со старыми значениями можно перестроить с новыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть конечно!

**1)** Создаете `ObservableList`

```
private ObservableList<XYChart.Data> datas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

**2)** Прописываете серию

```
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
```

**3)** Объявляете график

```
    @FXML
    public LineChart<Number,Number> ChartGraph;

    @FXML
    protected NumberAxis yAxis;

    @FXML
    protected NumberAxis xAxis;
```

**4)** Создаете серию и добавляете их в `ObservableList`

```
 series = new XYChart.Series();
 datas.add(new XYChart.Data(xValue,yValue));
```

**5)** Добавляете их на экран

```
 series.setData(datas);
 ChartGraph.getData().add(series);
```

Советую почитать документацию: [Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm), [Здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0820__JavaFX_LineChart.htm) и вот [Тут](http://java-buddy.blogspot.ru/2015/09/add-data-to-javafx-linechart-and-shift.html)